# MySQL Monitoring - Cloud Instances - No System Access

Tags: mysql, monitoring, sql, perfmon

Are there any MySQL monitoring suites/tools built to use on systems such as Amazon RDS where you do not have system access?  Looking for something beyond custom tools (nagios, zenoss, ganglia, hyperic) and more like MySQL Enterprise Monitor, MONyog, and DBTuna.

Comment: What kind of monitoring are you trying to get?  Very little is beyond nagios, xenoss, etc... plugin capabilities.  If you could give ups a hint about the type of statistics you're trying to collect, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try MONyog MySQL Monitor and Advisor from http://www.webyog.com.

Comment: No. That requires system access as I stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try appfirst with a mysql plugin.  It's easy to do.  You don't need nagios, but you get to use any of the nagios plugins.  Lots of rich tools for mysql.

Comment: Looks to require a collector.

Answer (score 0):

Two that I can recommend most are [Percona's PMM](https://docs.percona.com/percona-monitoring-and-management/index.html) and [Shattered Silicon's SSM](https://shatteredsilicon.net/mysql-monitoring-ssm/) (fork of PMM v1). Both support monitoring of remote database systems, and SSM has a few features that make it slightly better at monitoring RDS instances because it supports query data extraction from RDS via slow log.

PMM only supports query data extraction from performance_schema, which unfortunately doesn't cover information about queries that run as prepared statements, which can be quite a crippling drawback depending on how the application implements it's query execution.

Disclosure: I work with the maintainers of the SSM fork of PMM1